# How can an id of input field can be read by PHP?

Tags: php, html, input

I have an HTML input field, and I have every input field specified with some id, now how can I use this input field id to identify the field.

Example:

```
<input type='text' id='float' name='attributename' value='' maxlength='30'/>
```

I need to verify the id of input field for float and then insert the input field's value in to db in particular field.

Please help me out..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends which method you use for transferring the data (specified by the `method` attribute of the `form` element).

E.g. with:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type='text' id='float' name='attributename' value='' maxlength='30'/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

you can access the data in PHP via `$_POST['attributename']` when the form is submitted. `$_POST` is an associative array that holds the data send via a POST request.

**Note:** The `name` of the input element is the important property, not the ID. The ID is *not* transferred to the server, it plays only a role in the DOM. Only the `name` and the `value` is send to the server. So if you probably want to set `name="float"`.

**Further information:** [*Variables From External Sources*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php). You also might want to read about [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) (GET is the other method. This is used to send data via the URL).

Comment: You said " The ID is transferred to the server, it plays only a role in the DOM. " and then said "Only the name and the value is send to the server."

Is not it same thing ? do you mean that  ID is not transferred to the server,?

Comment: The word "not" is missing here, yes ;) Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can't. When POSTing data to the server, the `name` attribute is used. The `id` has nothing much to do with PHP.

Comment: Who Down Voted His Reply...??? Urs is Precise and one of the best Thanks N E WAYS

Answer (score 4):

When PHP gets the data by GET or POST, it doesn't know the id of the input that was associated with a given piece of data.  You do, however, know the name.

The simplest approach is to make the name and id match, or be able to derive the id from the name, like so:

```
name:  float
id: float_id

name: address
id: address_id
```

The reason is that the DOM uses the id, but it has nothing to do with PHP's execution.  PHP only gets the name.  Since you have control of both server-side and client-side code, you can determine what the id will be by choosing a naming convention as I suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit the form you would use the input `name=""` attribute to pull the value from:

```
$_POST['attributename'];
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, an `id` should be unique for each element.

You can suffix field name with `[]` to create an **array** so that you can process them later like:

```
<input type='text' id='float1' name='attributename[]' value='' maxlength='30'/>
<input type='text' id='float2' name='attributename[]' value='' maxlength='30'/>
<input type='text' id='float3' name='attributename[]' value='' maxlength='30'/>
```

Now from PHP, you can use `foreach` to access each field value like this:

```
foreach($_POST['attributename'] as $value){
  echo $value . '<br>';
}
```

If it is a single field though, you can access it just by its name:

```
echo $_POST['attributename'];
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you only have access to the `name` of the input, after the form has been submitted using `method="get"` or `method="post"`, through `$_GET['attributename']` and `$_POST['attributename']`, respectively.

Maybe you mean to target the field using javascript; you can do that by using `document.getElementById('float')`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deceze put it best.

Basically, everything in PHP (and all of web programming) requires key = value pairs. So, if you have no key, you in turn have no value. If the form element has only an ID and no NAME, then the variable that is passed to PHP will not exist.

The best way to test, is to have your HTML form element test with a "GET" instead of a "POST", this way, you will see the key=value pairs in the address bar when the form is submitted to the method by the action. All then you must do is use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` to pull the variables.