# How to include the id in the submission of the form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Goal: 
1. To include the id (in this example the id = 1) when the upload form is submitted so that it can be accessed in submit.php 
2. To insert the filename into the sql db depending on the id. 
Form:

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="1">
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" >
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Content">
</form>
```

Script:

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);
$('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);

function prepareUpload(event)
{
    files = event.target.files;
}

function uploadFiles(event)
  {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        data.append(key, value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php?files',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false, 
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log('Successfully uploaded the file');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log('Failed to upload the file');
        }
    });
}
```

submit.php

```
<?php 
  $data = array();

  if(isset($_GET['files']))
  { 
    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';

    foreach($_FILES as $file)
     {
       if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .basename($file['name'])))
       {
        $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];
        }
     else
       {
        $error = true;
       }
     }
   $data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your files') : array('files' => $files);
 }
 else
 {
  $data = array('success' => 'Form was submitted', 'formData' => $_POST);
 }

 echo json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500164/how-can-an-id-of-input-field-can-be-read-by-php  You may want to read this ...

Comment: Hi @Carlos! Thanks! But how do I get the id to be added in the data in jquery? The data currently holds the file I am uploading. I can't get the id to be appended or added..

Comment: Just be aware that people can change that value on the clienside before submitting it to PHP. Depending on what you're doing with it, it might be worth writing some checks on the backend side of things to make sure that value is actually what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your hidden field as

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_id" id="my_id" value="1">
```

And now within your jquery simply use

```
var my_id = $('#my_id').val();
```

And pass it with `data`

Comment: Hi @Narendra! Thanks! but how do I pass it with data where I join the id and the file?

Comment: Simply using `data.append('my_id',$('#my_id').val())`

Comment: Oh, is it ok if I use that even if I already have this line `data.append(key, value); ` ?

Comment: Well why don't you use `$_POST`

Answer (score 2):

Change your hidden field to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
```

Comment: Hi @Chayan! How do I get this with js so I can access it in submit.php?

Comment: you can put an id in the hidden field like id="xyz". and called in js as **$('#xyz').val();** to get value of that id.

Comment: And how did he called using `#` if he didn't have an `id`

Comment: @NarendraSisodia please read my previous comment. I tell him to put an id in the field with the name of **xyz**.

Comment: @Chayan, I can get the value that way but I can't get it added to the data (see `data: data,`) unless I use ( `data: { id: id}, ` ) but problem with the latter is I can't get the file.