# Access inputs value by ID in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, input

Can we access the value of an input in a CodeIgniter controller by ID ?

The post approach I know it very well, but let's say for whatever reason we have to get the value of an input by its ID. 
I want to know it there is an equivalent of the following jQuery code in CodeIgniter :

```
var myValue = $('#myInput').val();
```

Comment: Can't we ask questions nowadays without someone downvote it because it feels doing it ? 
I put this question before searching here and the CodeIgniter forums ... And sorry the downvoter if for you this isn't relevant, but I would like to know if it is possible

Comment: I want an equivalent of :  $id = $this->input->post('id');

Comment: Please go through this question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500164/how-can-an-id-of-input-field-can-be-read-by-php

Comment: Thank you av_ajesh ... You understood my question ... So the ID plays only a role in the DOM, and its not sent to the server